# How to generate the access token in Spring

Tags: java, oauth

How can I generate an access token in java spring?

I have tried to create an access token myself, but each time I need to do database operation that is taking a lot of time. Is there any easy way to generate access token?

Comment: If you mean oauth access tokens, then have a look at https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the jwt library. which will encode your data into 3 parts header, body payload and verified the signature.

https://jwt.io/

it is easy to encrypt and decrypt the token, you can able to find the jwt library for almost all languages.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean you need to do database operations to validate the token.

You can use JWT and validate that without database queries.
They have a java lib and you don't have to implement any of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you adopt JWT as the format of access tokens, you may be able to avoid DB operations. However, it would be better to compare pros & cons of JWT-based access tokens and DB-based access tokens. Especially, note that there is **no easy way to revoke JWT-based access tokens**. In addition, it is **impossible to change attributes of JWT-based access tokens** once they are issued.

The following table excerpted from *"7.1. Access Token Representation"* in *"[Full-Scratch Implementor of OAuth and OpenID Connect Talks About Findings](https://medium.com/@darutk/full-scratch-implementor-of-oauth-and-openid-connect-talks-about-findings-55015f36d1c3)"* lists characteristics of DB-based access tokens (*"Random String"* in the table) and JWT-based access tokens (*"Self-Contained"* in the table).

[image]